# Are there drawbacks to using a lambda and macro for error handling?

Tags: c++, c++11, error-handling

Properly testing function return values is fundamental, but it can quickly clutter the code and make it hard to read, like in the simple example below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  std::string filename("/usr/include/malloc.h");
  std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str());
  if (!ifs.is_open())
  {
    std::cerr << "Failed to open file " << filename << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  ifs.close();
  std::cout << "Passed the first error handling" << std::endl;

  filename = "/this/file/does/not/exist";
  ifs.open(filename.c_str());
  if (!ifs.is_open())
  {
    std::cerr << "Failed to open file " << filename << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have thought of a solution reducing cluttering by using a macro and c++11 lambda functions like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define RETURN_IF(X,Y,Z) if ( X ) { Y ; return Z; }

auto open_file_error = [](const std::string& filename)
{
  std::cerr << "Failed to open file " << filename << std::endl;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  std::string filename("/usr/include/malloc.h");
  std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str());
  RETURN_IF (!ifs.is_open(), open_file_error(filename), 1 );
  ifs.close();
  std::cout << "Passed the first error handling" << std::endl;

  filename = "/this/file/does/not/exist";
  ifs.open(filename.c_str());
  RETURN_IF (!ifs.is_open(), open_file_error(filename), 1 );
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the main function is less cluttered. Do you think that there are drawbacks to doing it like that or could it be a method to largely use?

Note that I use several macros to handle cases with or without a return value, for testing equality with a value, etc.

I propose the new version below to take into account two things:
- the answers and comments about the preference on using exceptions instead of return values;
- put away the emphasis on std::ifstream specific errors which are not the subject of the question.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <exception>

class OurExceptionForTheExternalLibraryFailure : public std::exception {};

#define CLEANUP_AND_THROW_IF(X,Y,Z) if ( X ) { Y ; throw Z; }

/* Return true in case of succes and false otherwise */
bool anyExternalFunction(const std::string& aString)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(aString.c_str());
    if (ifs.is_open())
    {
      ifs.close();
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
}

auto this_external_function_error_cleanup = [](const std::string& aString) 
{
  std::cerr << "The external function failed " << aString << std::endl;
  // other stuff
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  try 
  {
    std::string aString = "/usr/include/malloc.h";
    bool functionResult = anyExternalFunction(aString);
    CLEANUP_AND_THROW_IF (!functionResult, this_external_function_error_cleanup(aString), OurExceptionForTheExternalLibraryFailure() );
    std::cout << "Passed the first error handling" << std::endl;

    aString = "/this/file/does/not/exist";
    functionResult = anyExternalFunction(aString);
    CLEANUP_AND_THROW_IF (!functionResult, this_external_function_error_cleanup(aString), OurExceptionForTheExternalLibraryFailure() );
  } 
  catch (const OurExceptionForTheExternalLibraryFailure& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Catched OurExceptionForTheExternalLibraryFailure. There was an error" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What do you think about this new version (which still uses a macro, though...) ?

Comment: Another way to make the `main` function less cluttered is to write functions and call them.

Comment: I'd avoid as many dependencies on preprocessor magic as humanly possible.

Comment: _"As you can see, the main function is less cluttered."_ Well, that depends on POV. When reviewing your code I would always need to see the macro definition to get assured that it's doing what the macro name suggests.

Comment: Yes, you should refactor out that behaviour `(!ifs.is_open(), open_file_error(filename), 1 )`, to a function call if it's used more than once. Where I work we have a coding style guide that recommends against macros.  You should probably think about having a single exit point on the function too (so a single `return`)

Comment: Also, look into imbuing exceptions into your filestream if error handling becomes too burdensome: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions

Comment: @PeteBecker: well, everything is in main here to make a self-contained example, but the idea is to use this method in large projects with hundreds of classes and methods.

Comment: @erip: I agree. I'd like a solution entirely based on lambdas for example but I'm at the limits of my knowledge here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're right but good IDE will show you that by hovering. I agree that a solution with no macro would be better.

Comment: @AndyG: the precise error is not the subject here. The way of handling it is.

Comment: @CJBrew: we also vote against macros but there is use cases where they are useful…
With a function, how would you allow the caller to return if and only if the test is failed ?

Comment: @Kleag I'm not sure I understand what you're testing for, but I think explicit code is better than hiding simple boolean logic in a macro.

Comment: @CJBrew: I started to think at that solution after adding error handling to the call to the python c api like PyImport_ImportModule followed by PyList_Append and several PyObject_CallMethod. This made the function hard to read. Using my method make it easier to read while still handling errors.

Comment: What's the point of using a lambda function (as opposed to a normal function) when it's in global scope and not capturing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks okay to me. I wouldn't put all your eggs into this basket because you don't have to make it much more complicated to run into limitations with preprocessor syntax but, as it is, this is fine.

Comment: I will accept your answer as you mainly agree with me :-)

Anyway, thanks to the other contributors for their inputs and discussions.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you are already using lambdas, and you don't want all that testing code everywhere, you could always do something like (NOTE: uncompiled/untested code,)

```
template <typename FileReader>
void with_file(std::string file, FileReader&& reader) {
  std::ifstream in(file);
  if (in) {
    reader(in);
  } else {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open file: " + file); // NOTE: I'm being lazy here
  }
}

int main(...) {
  with_file("foo.txt", [](auto& in) {
    // do something with the stream
  });
}
```

.. but it's a matter of preference, I like exceptions, lambdas and small utility functions, but some may not...

Comment: Your solution is maybe good for the file opening example but it does not handle the general problem of breaking algorithm flow with function error return values handling. Or is there something I miss ?

Comment: ... well that wasn't part of the initial problem, anyway - return values are okay in some cases, but if it's exceptional - throw an exception...

Comment: I agree -- throwing an exception is a much better way to deal with this than comparing return values.

Comment: I have no power on the way external libraries are designed and I have to check their errors the way they are offered to me. If exception are a good way to handle errors is another question.

Comment: ...and now you have extended the problem again. :) You have to handle errors in the way the library designer has intended that they should be handled.. However when designing your own, you should pick what makes most sense...

Comment: @Kleag, as @Nim says, you just have to handle each function call. But you have the choice of how to deal with that on your own program level, and you significantly clean up YOUR code by using exceptions (as in my updated answer). In this case, my updated answer is far less coupled to the behaviour of ifstream::open and you can easily use a different method, simply change the failure test (currently `if( ifs.open(..)` and keep the `throw std::exception` bit on failure

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty much a textbook example of when to use exceptions.

You don't, however, have to write your own code to test for a file opening correctly, and throwing an exception (and so on) when it fails. Iostreams already support that fairly directly, so you can write code something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    try {
        std::ifstream in("/usr/include/malloc.h");
        in.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
        in.close();
        std::cout << "passed first test.\n";

        std::ifstream in2("/this/file/does/not/exist");
        in2.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
        in2.close();

        std::cout << "Passed second test\n";
    }
    catch (std::system_error &f) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file: " << f.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Of course, if you want to get the try/catch out of `main`, you can do that as well. I'm not sure you gain much from doing so though.

More generally, however, exceptions are clearly the right tool for this job. For other functions that don't provide a way to get exceptions reported as exceptions, you may have to write a wrapper of your own. Either way, however, if you have a function that has some range of normal return values, and one (or a few) "special" values in indicate failure (and similar) that's a pretty decent indication that it's indicating an exceptional condition via the return value--and the right way to deal with exceptional conditions is via exceptions rather than return values.

Rather than try to reiterate the (long) list of why/when/how to use exception handling, I'll refer you (as a starting point) to Herb Sutter's old article on [when and how to use exceptions](http://www.drdobbs.com/when-and-how-to-use-exceptions/184401836).

Comment: I like the `ifstream::exceptions` function, haven't seen that before. Whilst I think @Kleag is looking at a general case (not ifstream related), using exceptions in general is definitely the answer.

Comment: You're right @CJBrew. It's the general case that is interesting me. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: The general case is you define your own API and how it behaves. Therefore, your own classes and interfaces, and _you_ decide that it throws on errors. Then whatever 3rd party stuff you use, just implement your own API in terms of that.

Comment: @Jerry-Coffin I was about to suggest 
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Exceptional-C-Herb-Sutter/dp/0201615622

Comment: @CJBrew: it is a good book (as is [*More Exceptional C++*](http://www.amazon.com/More-Exceptional-Engineering-Programming-Solutions/dp/020170434X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1461776426&sr=8-1&keywords=more+exceptional+C%2B%2B)).

Comment: If you set failbit before opening will it not throw on the open?

Comment: @LokiAstari: I'd have to check to be sure--as a general rule, I always pass a file name to the ctor, so I essentially never have a situation where I do anything with the stream before opening.

Comment: Me too in general. But here you are throwing on a fail to `close()` may there not be other situations where it actually worked opening but failed closing. Note: The only situation where I don't open in the constructor is when adding a locale to the stream for special processing (but that is a very rare special case).

Comment: @LokiAstari: Right--and depending on the situation, failing to close might or might not be an error you care about. In essence, it's up to you to decide and disable the exception being thrown if it's not an error. Simple rule of thumb: if you were just reading from the file, failure to close probably isn't an error; if you were writing, chances that it's a real problem are much higher. The other side of it is that if you can't close the file, there may not be a whole lot you *can* do to fix things.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest this as a much cleaner example. NOW USING EXCEPTIONS... 
I haven't tested that it's 100% the same behaviour as your example (which I appreciate is just that; an example).

By the way, MFC has a "SUCCESS" macro that does a similar check to your "RETURN_IF". I don't like that macro either...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void TestForFileOpen(const std::string& filename) 
{
    std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str());
    if (!ifs.is_open())
    {
        throw std::exception("Failed");
    }
}

void ReportFileOpenFailure(const std::string& filename) 
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to open file " << filename << std::endl;
}

void NoisyTestForFileOpen(const std::string& filename)
{
    try
    {
        TestForFileOpen(filename);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        ReportFileOpenFailure(filename);
        throw;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
    std::string filename("/usr/include/malloc.h");

    try
    {
        NoisyTestForFileOpen(filename);

        std::cout << "Passed the first error handling" << std::endl;

        filename = "/this/file/does/not/exist";
        NoisyTestForFileOpen(filename);        
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A more general example with a custom API:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class IFileTester 
{
public:
    virtual ~IFileTester() {}

    // throws if file cannot be opened
    virtual void TestForFileOpen(const std::string& filename) const = 0;
};

class IfStreamFileTester : public IFileTester // implement as many versions as you need
{
public:
    virtual void TestForFileOpen(const std::string& filename) const
    {
        // implement this in terms of ifstream
        std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str());

        // thanks @Jerry-Coffin
        ifs.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
    }
};


void ReportFileOpenFailure(const std::string& filename) 
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to open file " << filename << std::endl;
}

void NoisyTestForFileOpen(const IFileTester& fileTester, const std::string& filename)
{
    try
    {
        fileTester.TestForFileOpen(filename);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        ReportFileOpenFailure(filename);
        throw;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
    IFileTester& fileTester = IfStreamFileTester();

    std::string filename("/usr/include/malloc.h");

    try
    {
        NoisyTestForFileOpen(fileTester, filename);

        std::cout << "Passed the first error handling" << std::endl;

        filename = "/this/file/does/not/exist";
        NoisyTestForFileOpen(fileTester, filename);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I'm not sure it generalizes well to all use cases of handling functions error handling. For example, the first test on success adds one level of indentation. If you have something like 10 calls to external functions (like I just had while embedding a python module inside my c++ module), this will not be more readable that standard way I put at the beginning of my question.

Comment: I'd argue this is sort of what exceptions are designed to do... Make your function calls to external code `throw` on errors. That way you don't have to worry about return at all.

Comment: @Kleag, Updated my answer, using exceptions instead.

Comment: I see. But then, I still have to encapsulate each external call into a function that can throw after testing the return value. Or to make several calls in one function but then we are back to the initial question of clutering with individual tests and throws.

Comment: If you're dealing with an external API it may well be worth wrapping it in your own class...  In which case you will have a wrapper function for each call or calls anyway, and can do all your own exception/failure handling there.